# Why InputStream does not take more memory?

Tags: java, performance, stream, heap-memory, httpsurlconnection

I have a case in which i need to get an api details as payload for an api,whose purpose is to invoke the payload api. Before invoking the api, we performs 2 operations in application layer.

1. we need to replace an environmental variables(if the user specifies).
2. And with the replaced data, we construct a json string(the input format) to give this as an input to another api.

While performing the above sequence of options i am getting Heap memory error for large payload.

So i tried streaming for replacing the environment variables.
Please refer below link which i have used for streaming.
http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-howto/replace-strings-in-streams-arrays-files.html

Questions :

1. why i was getting heap memory error while using String.replace() ?
2. Why inputStream doesnt take more in memory ?
3. How the streams are stored in memory ?

PS : If i try to convert to string i am getting heap memory error.

Thanks

Comment: It depends on the stream implementation.

Comment: I have implemented the stream as mentioned link. Any why the streams doesnt take the whole in memory ? where will the streams are persisted in storage ?

Comment: If you will provide us sample code that shows heap memory error, then it would be easier to guess where is the issue

Answer (score 0):

Problem could be because you are using String. String is immutable in Java. What it means is in more simple words is, every time you do some operation on your String, it keeps allocating more memory.

Simple alternate is use StringBuilder. It has all the required methods needed for you to work on basic string operations like replace, append, etc. and it will solve your memory problem as well.